# How to hide Ant Design 4 Date picker Year?

Tags: reactjs, antd, react-typescript

**[Ant design](http://Ant%20design)**  disable Date picker Year,
anyone know how to disable ant design react date time packer Year

Thanks
[image]
here the my code

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import moment from "moment";
import { DatePicker } from "antd";

function disabledYear(current) {
  let customYear = "11-25";
  return current && current < moment(customYear, "MM-DD");
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <DatePicker format="YYYY-MM-DD" disabledYear={disabledYear} />
  </div>,
  document.getElementById("container")
);
```

Comment: So you want a DatePicker where you only select the month and day? If so, why would you want the format to include YYYY?

Comment: I want to disable Picking  Year, can you look at my updated question

Comment: Right, so if you want to disable picking the year, what would YYYY be since you have `format="YYYY-MM-DD"`? Also in your `disabledYear` function, you only want dates before 11/25 to be selectable?

Comment: Look my updated image

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a coherent question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include this in your index.js as I believe you want to disable dates after 11-25. Your current condition will return true for all dates before 11-25 which will set all dates before 11-25 to be disabled

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import { DatePicker } from 'antd';
import moment from 'moment';
import './style.css';

function disabledYear(current) {
    let customYear = '11-25';
    return current && current > moment(customYear, 'MM-DD');
}

ReactDOM.render(
<div>
    <DatePicker format="YYYY-MM-DD" disabledDate={disabledYear} />
</div>,
document.getElementById('root')
);
```

And in your index.css add this to remove the year label and the year traversing buttons

```
.ant-picker-header > button.ant-picker-header-super-prev-btn,
button.ant-picker-header-super-next-btn,
button.ant-picker-year-btn {
      display: none !important;
}
```

Here's the screenshot after applying this code

[image]

Comment: Happy to help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-antd-datepicker-disabled-years?file=src/index.js).

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import { DatePicker } from 'antd';

function disabledYear(current) {
  // return current.year() === 2021; // disabling 2021
  // return current.year() !== 2021; // disabling everything besides 2021
  // return current.year() !== (new Date).getFullYear(); // disabling everything besides current year
  // return current.year() > 2021; // disabling everything further than 2021
  // return current.year() < 2021; // disabling everything in the past before 2021
  // return [2018, 2019].includes(current.year()); // disabling 2018 and 2019
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <DatePicker format="YYYY-MM-DD" disabledDate={disabledYear} />
  </div>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Hello there, Thanks for the answer, but actually i need the hide and disable i mentioned label , and disable click event

Answer (score 0):

Susmita Sil's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68212321/11335592) is correct, but has the drawback that EVERY DatePicker will be changed.

Better add your own css class to the 'dropdownClassName' property on the DatePicker-Component:

```
<DatePicker dropdownClassName='myCustomPicker' ...>
```

Then change your imported CSS:

```
.myCustomPicker .ant-picker-header > button.ant-picker-header-super-prev-btn, 
.myCustomPicker .ant-picker-header > button.ant-picker-header-super-next-btn, 
.myCustomPicker .ant-picker-header button.ant-picker-year-btn
{
  display: none !important;
}
```